# Failures in init.groovy.d scripts: null values returned

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to get Jenkins set up, with configuration, within a Docker environment. Per a variety of sources, it appears the suggested method is to insert scripts into JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d. I've taken scripts from places like the Jenkins wiki and made slight changes. They're only partially working. Here is one of them:

```
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
import java.util.logging.FileHandler
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
import java.util.logging.LogManager
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

// Log into a file
println("extralogging.groovy")

def RunLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("hudson.model.Run")
def logsDir = new File("/var/log/jenkins")
if (!logsDir.exists()) { logsDir.mkdirs() }

FileHandler handler = new FileHandler(logsDir.absolutePath+"/jenkins-%g.log", 1024 * 1024, 10, true);
handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
RunLogger.addHandler(handler)
```

This script fails on the last line, RunLogger.addHandler(handler).

```
2019-12-20 19:25:18.231+0000 [id=30]    WARNING j.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript#execute: Failed to run script file:/var/lib/jenkins/init.groovy.d/02-extralogging.groovy
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method addHandler() on null object
```

I've had a number of other scripts return NULL objects from various gets similar to this one:

```
def RunLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("hudson.model.Run")
```

My goal is to be able to develop (locally) a Jenkins implementation and then hand it to our sysops guys. Later, as I add pipelines and what not, I'd like to be able to also work on them in a local Jenkins configuration and then hand *something* for import into production Jenkins.

I'm not sure how to produce API documentation so I can chase this myself. Maybe I need to stop doing it this way and just grab the files that get modified when I do this via the GUI and just stuff the files into the right place.

Suggestions?

Comment: I did figure out how to print the log handlers -- there are a LOT, but not that one.

Comment: Do you need to develop groovy in your local workspace, then upload it to Jenkins web ?

Comment: @JRichardsz I'm trying to build a ready-to-go Docker container image with all our config. Ultimately I'd love to have a full export/import capability. I don't particularly care how I do it, just that I can do it. I thought init.groovy.d was the right path, but maybe there's a better way. I may just grab the files under /usr/lib/jenkins, and maybe that's the right path.